# What type of interference would occur between two frequencies that share the ratio 2:1?

Tags: waves, interference

Let's say I have two sine wave oscillations of 200Hz and 100Hz playing at the same time - what type of interference will I observe and why?

Comment: You will observe an additional frequency at 200 Hz + 100 Hz = 300Hz, when you detect the interference.

Answer (score 0):

When a signal is the superposition of two sinusoidal waves with a fixed phase difference the resulting signal in general can be described as a sinusoidal wave with a frequency which is the arithmetic average of the two original frequencies but with an amplitude which is varying with a frequency which is the semi-sum of those frequencies. So, in your case the resulting signal would behave as a signal at frequency $150$ Hz whose amplitude oscillates with frequency $50$ Hz  (frequency of beats).

Although the  math behind is connected to the properties of trigonometric functions, the simplest way to prove the result is by working with the complex representation of the time variation:
$$
y_1(t)=A_1 e^{i\omega_1 t} \\
y_2(t)=A_2 e^{i\omega_2 t}  \\
y(t)=y_1(t)+y_2(t)= A_1 e^{i\omega_1 t}+A_2 e^{i\omega_2 t} = \\=\left(A_1 e^{i \frac{ \left( \omega_1 - \omega_2 \right)}{2} t}+A_2 e^{-i \frac{ \left( \omega_1 - \omega_2 \right)}{2} t} \right) e^{i \frac{ \left( \omega_1 + \omega_2 \right)}{2} t}
$$

As far as the "*why?*", the answer is more difficult if you are looking for something more intuitive than just mathematical formulae. Pictures like the last in [this web page](https://www.acs.psu.edu/drussell/demos/superposition/superposition.html) may help in visualizing things but they do not go really deeper than the formulae.

Comment: Thanks for this elaborative answer! I asked this question because I was told in music class that when two musical notes which are either 2:1 or 3:2 apart from one another are played together their resultant tone is weak. He explained it by saying that they very closely share harmonics and hence one frequency overpowers the other. I got confused because in physics I had learnt that constructive interference such as above leads to an increase in amplitude.

Comment: @Aman Trivedi Confusion is understandable.  As soon as harmonics are mentioned, this implies that the sound is not made by a single frequency anymore (which is usually the case for all musical sounds). Basically, any sound  generated by a string or by air in a pipe, corresponds  to a sum of many harmonics (multiple of a fundamental frequency) of decreasing amplitude. Another important thing one has to take into account is that the sound experience is further filtered by the behavior of the human ear. The physical level is just the starting point of the whole story.

Comment: This wikipedia page  ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(music) ) provides a reasonably self contained account of the main facts about harmonics.